# Jest Unit Tests on Teamcity

Tags: vue.js, continuous-integration, jestjs, teamcity

We have a Vue.js app that uses jest and jest teamcity reporter, the problem is when I run on teamcity I am getting below errors

```
  Trace: The node type SpreadProperty has been renamed to SpreadElement
      at Object.isSpreadProperty (D:\BuildAgent\work\87cb20bee7187581\SMA Web\SMA.Web\node_modules\@babel\core\node_modules\@babel\types\lib\validators\generated\index.js:4304:11)
      at hasSpread (D:\BuildAgent\work\87cb20bee7187581\SMA Web\SMA.Web\node_modules\babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread\lib\index.js:38:13)
      at PluginPass.ObjectExpression (D:\BuildAgent\work\87cb20bee7187581\SMA Web\SMA.Web\node_modules\babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread\lib\index.js:234:14)
      at newFn (D:\BuildAgent\work\87cb20bee7187581\SMA Web\SMA.Web\node_modules\@babel\core\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\visitors.js:193:21)
      at NodePath._call (D:\BuildAgent\work\87cb20bee7187581\SMA Web\SMA.Web\node_modules\@babel\core\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\path\context.js:53:20)
      at NodePath.call (D:\BuildAgent\work\87cb20bee7187581\SMA Web\SMA.Web\node_modules\@babel\core\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\path\context.js:40:17)
      at NodePath.visit (D:\BuildAgent\work\87cb20bee7187581\SMA Web\SMA.Web\node_modules\@babel\core\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\path\context.js:88:12)
      at TraversalContext.visitQueue (D:\BuildAgent\work\87cb20bee7187581\SMA Web\SMA.Web\node_modules\@babel\core\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\context.js:118:16)
      at TraversalContext.visitMultiple (D:\BuildAgent\work\87cb20bee7187581\SMA Web\SMA.Web\node_modules\@babel\core\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\context.js:85:17)
      at TraversalContext.visit (D:\BuildAgent\work\87cb20bee7187581\SMA Web\SMA.Web\node_modules\@babel\core\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\context.js:144:19)
```

My teamcity steps looks like below
[image]

Also If I run from cmd from the build agent directly, I can see tests running though,

Can anyone point what could be the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs to be added in package.json file in order to identify and run unit tests under teamcity.

```
"jest": {
    "testResultsProcessor": "jest-teamcity-reporter"
}
```